# ExcludeExitNodes for the Netherlands not working

Tags: tails, exit-relays

Logged in as admin then used:

sudo nano /etc/tor/torrc

ExcludeExitNodes {us},{au},{ca},{nz},{gb},{fr},{nl}

CTRL-X

sudo systemctl restart tor

{us},{au},{ca},{nz},{gb},{fr} does work
{nl} does NOT work?

Has the Netherlands got another country code?

Comment: Tor's geoip database follows ISO 3166 country codes, so "nl" should be the correct country code for the Netherlands. How specifically does it not work? Does tor give an error message? Do you see circuits with exits in the Netherlands?

Comment: No error message, it allows the Netherlands {nl} to become an exit node notwithstanding ExcludeExitNodes {nl}

Comment: Did you reopen the torrc to check if it saved? What happens if you put nl in another position in the list instead of the end?